# I want to use timerOnce for delay but it doesnt work

Tags: timer, spring-statemachine

I want to go from status **REPEATED_EXPORT_TO_A** to status **EXPORT_TO_A_AGAIN** with a delay but action **reexportEvent()** has not execute. I have the following state machine :

```
    public StateMachineBuilder.Builder<StatusId, ActionId> construct(StateMachineBuilder.Builder<StatusId, ActionId> builder) throws Exception {
builder.configureStates().withStates()
        .states(ImmutableSet.of(OBTAINED_BY_B, FOR_EXPORT_TO_A, EXPORTING_TO_A,
                EXPORT_TO_A_ERROR, EXPORTING_TO_A_TIMEOUT,
                RECEIVED_BY_A, NOT_RECEIVED_BY_A, RECEIVED_A_ERROR, REPEATED_EXPORT_TO_A))
        .state(FOR_EXPORT_TO_A, checkPassedAction(), null)
        .state(EXPORTING_TO_A, exportedAction(), null)

        .choice(EXPORTED_TO_A_OR_NOT)
        .choice(EXPORT_TO_A_AGAIN);

builder.configureTransitions().withExternal()
        .source(OBTAINED_BY_B).target(FOR_EXPORT_TO_A)
        .and().withExternal()
        .source(FOR_EXPORT_TO_A).target(EXPORTED_TO_A_OR_NOT)

        .and().withChoice()
        .source(EXPORTED_TO_A_OR_NOT)
        .first(EXPORTING_TO_A, exportingToAGuardSsm)
        .last(REPEATED_EXPORT_TO_A)

        .and().withExternal()
        .source(REPEATED_EXPORT_TO_A)
        .target(EXPORT_TO_A_AGAIN)
        .event(REEXPORT_TO_A)

        .and().withChoice()
        .source(EXPORT_TO_A_AGAIN)
        .first(EXPORTING_TO_A, exportingToAGuardSsm)
        .then(EXPORT_TO_A_ERROR, checkRepeatExportGuard)
        .then(REPEATED_EXPORT_TO_A, repeatExportToBGuardSsm)
        .last(EXPORT_TO_A_ERROR)
```

This internal transition for delay

```
   .and().withInternal()
    .source(REPEATED_EXPORT_TO_A)
    .action(reexportEvent())
    .timerOnce(5000)
```

but this action has not execute

```
 private Action<StatusId, ActionId> reexportEvent() {
    //some code
      return context -> {
          Doc doc = SsmUtil.getDoc(context);
          doc.setRepeatCount(doc.getRepeatCount() + 1);
          context.getStateMachine().sendEvent(REEXPORT_TO_A);
      };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one key thing to understand for triggers in Spring State Machine - they are associated with a state and you need to remain in that state for the trigger to execute. The delay starts the moment you enter the state - if you exit from the state before the delay time is reached, the trigger does not execute.

Example:

- specify a trigger for state "A" with a 5 second delay
- enter state "A"
- on 2nd second exit state "A"

The trigger will not execute, because you've exited from state "A" before the defined time delay has expired.

Checkout a unit test (TestTriggersDelay) that demos this behavior [here](https://github.com/hovanessyan/spring-statemachine-triggers).